# Manage Visio 2013 organization chart with excel on SharePoint?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, visio, office-2013

is it possible to have an Excel document on SharePoint that I can then use to create Visio Organization Chart? My goal is to be able to edit the excel that will in turn update the Visio Organization Chart.

Is this possible? I am not really interested in 3rd party solutions that cost money.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible to some extent.. You can have Visio diagram in sharepoint auto-update from excel data when you change some values in excel sheet for shapes which already exist on the daigram (like name of a person for example). But you can't make sharepoint or visio auto-generate diagram when you add or delete persons in excel file, or when some person changes it's position for example, i.e. the functionality to automatically add/delete or move the shapes on diagram depending on the data in excel does not exist.

Also note stackoverflow is basically focusing on questions related to programming in some way, so you may try other places.